# MinGW console application

Tags: c, mingw, mingw-w64

Ok I've just started programming in C and I've found the MinGW compiler to be just what I need (easy to compile and run your application). I've written simple hello_world app and I just wanted it to print the result on the screen just to see if everything works fine. It doesn't output anything but it rather compiles it to .exe file and then when I run that file it prints the result. How to make a console application using MinGW. I've googled and read some documentation but can't quite get the answer.

This is the line i compile my code with:
    gcc hello_world.c

**Edit:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
   int n = 10;
   printf("hello world %d\n",n);
   return 0;
}
```

I've tried using cmd and powershell but i don't think that's the issue.

Comment: Please post your code, even when it is only a hello world. Did you executed the executable in the command shell or PowerShell?

Comment: Post edited, don't know if you get the notif if i edit the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *have* created a console application.

```
gcc hello_world.c
```

asks gcc to compile and link `hello_world.c` into an executable,
without telling it what you want the executable to be called. So it
defaults to `a.exe` (on Windows) or `a.out` (on Unix/Linux).

That `a.exe` *is* your console application. You can run it in the
console (a.k.a shell, command-prompt) and, as you've seen, it does
what you expect.

If you would like the executable to have a particular name you
have to tell gcc that, e.g.

```
gcc -o hw hello_world.c
```

`-o` is for "output". This will make you a program called `hw.exe`.

I suspect also that you may think there is some command:

```
gcc ??? hello_world.c
```

That will compile, link *and run* your program. There isn't. Compilers
don't run programs, they just make programs, that you can take away and
run independently of the compiler.

I recommend that you learn something about using gcc before you
go any further. Here is [a pretty good beginners' tutorial](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html).
And for definitive guidance, consult [the official documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)

Comment: Great answer. I knew the part about the output file and how to name it,  but I thought there was a way to do just that what you mentioned (compile, link and run my program). Thanks for the tutorial since I have no clue what gcc exactly is, because I just wanted to get to programming and googled c compiler and didn't notice that mingw just offers standalone c compiler. Thanks again for clarifying things for me a little bit